# SQL SELECT id WHERE emails are the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I do not know if it's possible at all, but I have two tables, **userBasic** and **carPlateConfidence**, in carPlateConfidence I would like to insert id of userBasic where emails are matched.

```
$query .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO userBasic (id_uM, userNameG, userEmailG) values ((SELECT id_uM FROM userMore WHERE userEmailG='$userEmailG'),'$userNameG', '$userEmailG');";

$query .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO carPlateConfidence (emailConfid, id_uB,plateNumber, confidencePlate, plateNumberUn) values ('$userEmailG', (SELECT id_uB FROM userBasic WHERE userEmailG='(SELECT max(emailConfid) FROM carPlateConfidence)'), '$plateNumber','$confidencePlate', '$plateNumberUn');";
```

So if I have:

userBasic:

```
id_uM = 555;
userNameG = BlaBla;
userEmailG = blabla@blabla.com
```

And in this table I would like

carPlateConfidence:

```
emailConfid = blabla@blabla.com;
id_uB = 555
plateNumber = 1111
confidencePlate = 70 
plateNumberUn = 2222
```

AND if email do not matched:

```
emailConfid = blabla2@blabla.com;
id_uB = NULL
plateNumber = 1111
confidencePlate = 70
plateNumberUn = 222
```

**P>S>** Currently I have tried this, to select id from userBasic:

```
(SELECT id_uB FROM userBasic WHERE userEmailG='(SELECT max(emailConfid) FROM carPlateConfidence)')
```

**id_uB** in **carPlateConfidence** is set as foreign key;

Tables:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `carPlateConfidence`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `carPlateConfidence`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carPlateConfidence` (
  `id_cof` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_uB` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emailConfid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `plateNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `confidencePlate` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plateNumberUn` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cof`),
  KEY `id_uB` (`id_uB`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `userBasic`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `userBasic`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userBasic` (
  `id_uB` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_uM` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userNameG` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `userEmailG` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_uB`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userEmailG` (`userEmailG`),
  KEY `id_uM` (`id_uM`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=119 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `carPlateConfidence`
--
ALTER TABLE `carPlateConfidence`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `carPlateConfidence_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_uB`) REFERENCES `userBasic` (`id_uB`);

--
-- Constraints for table `userBasic`
--
ALTER TABLE `userBasic`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `userBasic_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_uM`) REFERENCES `userMore` (`id_uM`);
```

Comment: It is possible easily.Can you post your table structure ?

Comment: @Bikash P I add structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want an update, not an insert :

```
UPDATE carPlateConfidence t
SET t.id_uB = (SELECT distinct s.id_uM FROM userBasic s
               WHERE s.userEmailG = t.emailConfid)
```

This will work only if there can be only 1 match, if there can be more then one match you should specify which one you want, if it doesn't matter, either use `MAX()` or `limit` :

```
UPDATE carPlateConfidence t
SET t.id_uB = (SELECT max(s.id_uM) FROM userBasic s
               WHERE s.userEmailG = t.emailConfid)
```

Comment: Or limit for that matter:)

Comment: Any way to use insert? I need to insert new values not just to update the table.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, how can there be a match between emails, and in the same time a record doesn't exsits???

Comment: @sagi One question, if id_uB is foreign I should drop constrain, update, add constrain?